# Create a table with one array of objects, but the objects have different keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I'm making an application that reads one or multiple databases, with different names and number of columns and creates a report screen and also exports this table. So when I use at least two databases and turn them into just one database to create just one table, the part of the table header with the columns works fine, creating all the columns even if one of the databases doesn't have the columns that the other bank owns. But the table rows with the values ​​are not in the right position. Let's say I have 10 columns in the first database and 10 columns in the second database, so only the rows referring to the first 10 columns are filled, but what would be certain would be that some rows would have values ​​in the first 10 columns and other rows would have to have values ​​in the 10 last columns.

The table is looking like this:

| ID | InspectionTime | Q1_1 | Q1_2 | Q1_FrontalEntrada | Q1_FrontalSaida |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |  |

But she should be like this:

| ID | InspectionTime | Q1_1 | Q1_2 | Q1_FrontalEntrada | Q1_FrontalSaida |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |  | 2 | 2 |

The JSON is much longer than this, but here's the important part of it:

```
[
      {
        Id: 17756,
        InspectionTime: "2023-01-20T08:17:50.6674652",
        PartId: 2,
        PartNumberId: 18,
        Result: 1,
        Q1_1: "1",
        Q1_2: "1",
        Q2_1: "1",
        Q2_2: "1",
        Q3_1: "1"
      },
      {
        Id: 14285,
        InspectionTime: "2023-01-20T08:17:55.3546448",
        PartId: 1,
        PartNumberId: 39,
        Result: 1,
        Q1_FrontalEntrada: "1",
        Q1_FrontalSaida: "1",
        Q2_FrontalEntrada: "1",
        Q2_FrontalSaida: "1",
        Q3_FrontalEntrada: "1"
      }
    ]
```

So with this example the table has 15 columns, 5 that are the same in all databases, plus 5 from each of the 2 databases that are different from each other. However, in the lines of the table, only the first 10 columns are filled in, leaving the last 5 blank, but the correct thing would be when it is a value from the first database to have the value in the first 10 columns, and when it is data from the second database data have the value of the first 5 columns, 5 empty columns and then the rest of the data in the last 5 columns

Here are my code snippets:

```
const dataDetailedKeys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...
  dataFilteredDetailed // JSON with the data
));

<div>
  {
    dataDetailedKeys
      .map((data, id) => {
        return (
          <div key={id}>
            <p>
              {data}
            </p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
</div>



const dataDetailedValues = Object.values(Object.assign({}, ...
  dataDefault // O JSON with the data
));

paginateData // JSON with the data but using a pagination library for the table
  .map((data, id) => {
    return (
      <div key={id}>
        <div>
          {
            dataDetailedValues.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={index}>
                  <p>
                    {Object.values(data)[index]}
                  </p>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to follow all of the code you have posted. However, I think your issue is that you loop over each value in each object without any regard to the keys. This will mean that no columns will be skipped because the the loop is unaware of the columns (which correspond to the keys).

Therefore the change would be to do a loop through each key (from a list of all keys from all objects) for *each* item in your data array. You would render each item's value at each key - and if the item have no value for a particular key, then that column will be empty.

You could dynamically construct your array of keys by combining the keys of the first object in each data set. For the code below, I will just use a hard-coded array of keys for simplicity.

The important part of the code below is that we `map` over our items array to create our table rows and then, for each row, we map over the `keys` so that the values of each item populate the correct column.

```
const keys = [
  "Id",
  "InspectionTime",
  "PartId",
  "PartNumberId",
  "Result",
  "Q1_1",
  "Q1_2",
  "Q2_1",
  "Q2_2",
  "Q3_1",
  "Q1_FrontalEntrada",
  "Q1_FrontalSaida",
  "Q2_FrontalEntrada",
  "Q2_FrontalSaida",
  "Q3_FrontalEntrada"
];

const items = [{
    Id: 17756,
    InspectionTime: "2023-01-20T08:17:50.6674652",
    PartId: 2,
    PartNumberId: 18,
    Result: 1,
    Q1_1: "1",
    Q1_2: "1",
    Q2_1: "1",
    Q2_2: "1",
    Q3_1: "1"
  },
  {
    Id: 14285,
    InspectionTime: "2023-01-20T08:17:55.3546448",
    PartId: 1,
    PartNumberId: 39,
    Result: 1,
    Q1_FrontalEntrada: "1",
    Q1_FrontalSaida: "1",
    Q2_FrontalEntrada: "1",
    Q2_FrontalSaida: "1",
    Q3_FrontalEntrada: "1"
  }
];

const Table = () => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {keys.map(key => <th key={key}>{key}</th>)}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              {keys.map(key => <td key={`${index}_${key}`}>{item[key]}</td>)}
            </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
};
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/fbtnsy36/) for reference.